# Reverse word problem - program stuck in input loop?

Tags: c++, file-read

I am trying to solve the reverse word problem. My solution works, and even skips blank lines. However, after all the lines of a file are read, the program gets stuck in a loop, constantly accepting input. This is very puzzling, and I feel like it has to do with my outer while loop, but I can't see what's wrong with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    stack<string> s;
    ifstream in;
    in.open(argv[1]);
    do
    {
        do
        {
            string t;
            in >> t;
            s.push(t);
        } while(in.peek() != '\n');
        do
        {
            cout << s.top();
            s.pop();
            if(s.size() > 0) cout << " ";
            else cout << endl;
        } while(s.size() > 0);
    } while(in.peek() != -1 || in.fail() || in.eof() || in.bad() );
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check [here](http://smart2help.com/e-books/ticpp-2nd-ed-vol-one/Frames.html). Search for string **C02:GetWords.cpp** in the page. You'll get a nice solution from Bruce Eckels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the inner loop. If I give in a text file containing only one word on a single line, it will fail since it will never come out of the inner loop.

This code works for me:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    stack<string> s;
    ifstream in;
    in.open(argv[1]);
    do
    {
        do
        {
            string t;
            in >> t;
            s.push(t);
        } while((in.peek() != '\n') && (in.peek() != -1));
        do
        {
            cout << s.top();
            s.pop();
            if(s.size() > 0) cout << " ";
            else cout << endl;
        } while(s.size() > 0);
    } while(in.peek() != -1 && !(in.fail()) && !(in.eof()) && !(in.bad()) );
    in.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Sriram

Comment: The problem is worse. The inner loop is the one to detect end-of-file, but at that state `peek` returns -1, so it will never exit.

Comment: @Jan: Yes, you are correct. I tried the code out and came up with some edits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that may work.

```
// read the file line by line
string line;
while (std::getline(in, line))
{
  if (!line.empty())
  {
    // now have a valid line, extract all the words from it
    <input string stream> in_str(line); // construct a input string stream with the string
    string word;
    while (in_str >> word)
    {
      // push into the stack
    }
    // now print the contets of the stack
  }
  else
    // print a blank line(?)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last condition should just be `while(in)`.

Comment: No dice. The exact same situation is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `while(in >> t) {...}`

Comment: This will not work, as it will read the entire file instead of just one line.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I think it reads word by word and at end of file returns 0. I verified this in a book (Thinking in C++ vol one). Please check [here](http://smart2help.com/e-books/ticpp-2nd-ed-vol-one/Frames.html). Search for string **C02:GetWords.cpp**

Comment: You are right, it reads word by word, but the OP wants to read all words of one line, reverse them, then read all words of the next line etc. This does not work with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
while(in.peek() != -1 || in.fail() || in.eof() || in.bad() );
```

should surely be:

```
while(in.peek() != -1 && (! in.fail()) && (!  in.eof()) && (! in.bad()) );
```

Alternatively, and better, just test the stream:

```
while( in && in.peek != -1 )
```

And I think that -1 should actually be EOF.